# jquery .focus() in Firefox: functionally it works, but visually, it does not

Tags: jquery, firefox, focus

After doing a little research, it seems this is not an uncommon problem.

As my title says, just doing

```
$("#myelement").focus();
```

works, but it does not visually appear that the focus is set on that element.

Some people suggested doing

```
$("#myelement").trigger('focus');
```

and once again, this works, but visually it does not.

I'm not looking to do blur or setTimeOut or focusout anything like that, just a straight 
focus.

NOTE: this is only an issue in FireFox, not in Chrome.

Any input is appreciated on how to get this working. We use focus quite a bit in this product we are building.

Comment: can you explain it in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: FYI `$("#myelement")` is not the same as `$("myelement")` first one looks for an element with the id `myelement` the other looks for element tags named `myelement`.

Comment: Right you are, @PatrickEvans. It was a typo :)

Comment: @SamBattat I mean, pretty straightforward: http://jsfiddle.net/MgAFy/14/ Works fine in Chrome, 'works' in Firefox but VISUALLY you cannot see the focus.

Comment: And note: if I do that fiddle in chrome, visually you can see the focus. In firefox, you cannot.

Comment: @DnfD The fiddle you linked doesn't work on Firefox on a Mac at all, visually or otherwise. I'm using version 33.1.1, which is the most recent version as of today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, oddly enough, the website www.google.com was my friend in this...literally. I opened up the page in FF and notice the two input buttons below the search form have a focus also. Inspected it, and they seem to be doing it in the css.

So my answer simply was

```
input.btn:focus {
  enter style here;
}
```

I tried setTimeOut, preventDefault, and a couple other minor workarounds to no avail. Never knew you could set focus in CSS, pretty cool.

Any input on this is welcome.

Comment: You can't set focus through CSS. The CSS in your answer will be applied _if the input is focused_. It in no way _sets_ focus.